# JavaFX 8 TableView filtering

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I read this article: 
http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/
but I Have problem with column that contains Long value not String.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> personTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, Long> lastNameColumn;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // 0. Initialize the columns.
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> cellData) -> {
        return cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty();
    });

    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>,
            ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty("str"); // HERE IS OK
        }
    });

lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Long>, ObservableValue<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Long> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Long> param) {
        return new SimpleLongProperty(14L); // HERE IS WRONG 
        // Incompatible types.
        // Required: ObservableValue<java.lang.Long>
        // Found: SimpleLongProperty
    }
});
```

I write in code where is error.

Anyone know, what I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat counterintuitively, `LongProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>`, not `ObservableValue<Long>`. The easiest fix, if it works for your requirements, would be to make your `TableColumn` type `Number`:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, Number> lastNameColumn;

lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Number> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Number> param) {
        return new SimpleLongProperty(14L); 

    }
});
```

If you really need the column type to be `Long`, then you will need to do

```
lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Long>, ObservableValue<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Long> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Long> param) {
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<Long>(14L); 

    }
});
```